# Cant make sure only one thread is talking to a device - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, tkinter, python-multithreading

Ive got three threads.

- One for getting Data from a device.
- One for calculation something
- and the last is a tkinter thread.
  Everytime one of these threads has an error a Device needs to be resetted. So every thread needs to call the reset function.
  Here are some pieces of code:

```
lock = threading.Lock()
upda = threading.Thread(target=updater,args=(lock,))
upda.start()
regel = threading.Thread(target=regelung,args=(lock,))
regel.start()

root.mainloop()
```

The locks in the **upda** and **regel** thread work great (they need the lock to safely comuicate with the device per USB)

```
    
def reset_to_0():
    
    try:
        #reset device
     
        
    except Exception as e:
        log.error("Fehler beim Reset" + str(e))
```

This code needs a lock as well in order to communicate with the device.
But no matter what I try it doesnt work.
When I use the lock as a global variable I get the error **'_thread.lock' has no attribute 'aquire'**

And if I try to reset without the lock I sometimes get: device reports readiness to read but returned no data (device disconnected or multiple access on port?)

How do I make sure that everytime I talk to the device another thread doesnt interfere?

Comment: You misspelled `acquire`. Always read errors carefully (tells you there is no attribute `aquire`). Also look at how to use `with lock: ...`. It's much simpler and automatically releases the lock

Comment: always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

Comment: maybe first run code without `try/except` to see FULL error message.

Comment: @TheLizzard your completely right. I copied the line from a place where is was working (which is curios looking at it now)